# Installing Windows XP Support Tools (to get WinDiff) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

Is there anything wrong with installing [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546) on Windows 7?  In particular, I want to use WinDiff.  If this should not be done, then how else can I install WinDiff on Windows 7?

Comment: Gee, did you try googling "windiff"? http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm

Answer (score 0):

> A version of WinDiff.exe (6.1.7716.0, dated 13May2010) that I have found to operate flawlessy on a 7601 build (AMD64) may be found in the MicrosoftSDKs/Windows/v7.1/Bin folder when you install Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4

- source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/0d51abcd-3b76-495b-84a4-45e188f6d9f6/windiff-for-windows-7

According to the above there should be a Windows 7 compatible version in the Windows SDK For Windows 7 And .Net Framework 4. I could not find a release with the same publication date specified in the post, but it appears you can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442 . I would suggest trying that version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Windows Server 2003 Version:

[Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 32-bit Support Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7911)